# Predicting values using an OLS model with statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

I calculated a model using OLS (multiple linear regression). I divided my data to train and test (half each), and then I would like to predict values for the 2nd half of the labels.

```
model = OLS(labels[:half], data[:half])
predictions = model.predict(data[half:])
```

The problem is that I get and error:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statsmodels-0.5.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 281, in predict
    return np.dot(exog, params)
    ValueError: matrices are not aligned

I have the following array shapes:
data.shape: (426, 215)
labels.shape: (426,)

If I transpose the input to model.predict, I do get a result but with a shape of (426,213), so I suppose its wrong as well (I expect one vector of 213 numbers as label predictions):

```
model.predict(data[half:].T)
```

Any idea how to get it to work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For statsmodels >=0.4, if I remember correctly

`model.predict` doesn't know about the parameters, and requires them in the call
see http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict.html

What should work in your case is to fit the model and then use the predict method of the results instance.

```
model = OLS(labels[:half], data[:half])
results = model.fit()
predictions = results.predict(data[half:])
```

or shorter

```
results = OLS(labels[:half], data[:half]).fit()
predictions = results.predict(data[half:])
```

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.predict.html  with missing docstring

Note: this has been changed in the development version (backwards compatible), that can take advantage of "formula" information in predict
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.predict.html

Comment: Although this is correct answer to the question BIG WARNING about the model fitting and data splitting. You should have used 80% of data (or bigger part) for training/fitting and 20% ( the rest ) for testing/predicting. Splitting data 50:50 is like Schrodingers cat. We have no confidence that our data are all good or all wrong. 
Thus confidence in the model is somewhere in the middle. We want to have better confidence in our model thus we should train on more data then to test on.

Comment: The 70/30 or 80/20 splits are rules of thumb for small data sets (up to hundreds of thousands of examples). This should not be seen as THE rule for all cases. In deep learning where you often work with billions of examples, you typically want to train on 99% of the data and test on 1%, which can still be tens of millions of records. A 50/50 split is generally a bad idea though.

Comment: As long as your resutls are statisticaly significant, they are acceptable. For example, in a case where your data is highly unbalanced, none of the above-mentioned methods result in a statistically significant comparison because the data is highly biased and even a simple averaging will resutl in frequently correct answers!!!

Answer (score 6):

You can also call [`get_prediction`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.get_prediction.html) method of the `Results` object to get the prediction together with its error estimate and confidence intervals.
Example:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3.5, 4])
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()
```

predict:

```
# Predict at x=2.5
X_test = np.array([1, 2.5])  # "1" refers to the intercept term
results.get_prediction(X_test).summary_frame(alpha=0.05)  # alpha = significance level for confidence interval
```

gives:

```
    mean    mean_se mean_ci_lower   mean_ci_upper   obs_ci_lower    obs_ci_upper
0   3.675   0.198431    2.821219    4.528781    2.142416    5.207584
```

where `mean_ci` refers to the *confidence interval* and `obs_ci` refers to the *prediction interval*.