# Meaning of arguments passed to statsmodels OLS.predict

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm using the [Old Faithful Geyser Dataset](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/all-of-statistics/=data/faithful.dat) to learn some introductory linear regression and prediction. The dataset contains two features; time since last eruption and the duration of the subsequent eruption:

```
    eruptions   waiting
0   3.600   79
1   1.800   54
2   3.333   74
3   2.283   62
4   4.533   85
```

Here is the summary data:

[image: Old faithful dataset summary]

Here's the model:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = faithful.waiting
X = sm.add_constant(X)
y = faithful.eruptions

model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()
```

My question arises when trying to make a prediction using `predict()`. For example, If I have just waited 75 minutes, how long will this eruption last?

```
results.predict([1, 75]) # 1 needs to be passed, I don't know why
```

Why pass 1? Is it because the `add_constant(X)` added 1?:

```
    const   waiting
0   1.0   79
1   1.0   54
2   1.0   74
3   1.0   62
4   1.0   85
```

The [docs](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict.html) say that the main argument is "Parameters of a linear model"
The only variable is wait time (75mins) and the regression line has it's own intercept anyway (-1.87):

```
results.params
>>>
const     -1.874016
waiting    0.075628
dtype: float64
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218461/predicting-values-using-an-ols-model-with-statsmodels) notes that:

> `model.predict` doesn't know about the parameters, and requires them in the call

However if that's the case would -1.87 not be the best argument?

Any help greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: note the distinction between `model.predict` and `results.predict`. The results instance "knows" the estimated parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are learning parameters for an equation of the form `y = Ax + b`
Your model says that `A = 0.075628` and `b = -1.87` (b is the bias term)
You pass two values x = 75 and the multiplier for b is 1.

You can also run predict as,
`results.predict(sm.add_constant([75], has_constant='add'))`